# How to implement Join for this below script for avoiding nested script

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT UserDCID AS UserDCCompForDelCount1
FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDCComponent AS udc
WHERE(
    UserDCID IN(
        SELECT UserDCID FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud WHERE (
            UserID NOT IN(
                SELECT UserID FROM CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query

```
SELECT UserDCID AS UserDCCompForDelCount1 
FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDCComponent AS udc 
INNER JOIN CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud ON udc.UserDCID=ud.UserDCID
INNER JOIN CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs ON ud.UserDCID=cs.UserID
```

Comment: Its there as "not in" from CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity. Yours will not give desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query

```
SELECT UserDCID AS UserDCCompForDelCount1 FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDCComponent AS udc 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT UserDCID FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud 
      EXCEPT 
      SELECT UserID FROM CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs
     )Table T
ON T.UserDCID = udc.UserDCID
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the inner queries:

```
SELECT UserDCID FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud WHERE (
    UserID NOT IN(
        SELECT UserID FROM CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs
    )
)
```

They select the rows from table `ud` that don't have a match in table `cs`, joining the tables using the field `UserID` which is present in both of them.

The query can be written as a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ud.UserDCID
FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud
  LEFT JOIN CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs
      ON ud.UserID = cs.UserID        # join the tables on common field `UserID`
WHERE cs.UserID IS NULL               # the row from `ud` has no match in `cs`
```

Back to the big query (I stripped the part that was refactored above because stays in the way for the explanation below):

```
SELECT UserDCID AS UserDCCompForDelCount1
FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDCComponent AS udc
WHERE(
    UserDCID IN (
        SELECT UserDCID ...
        )
    )
)
```

This query selects the rows from `udc` that have matches in the result set produced by the inner query (the stripped one) when `udc` and the result set are joined by field `UserDCID` which is present in both.

This is a simple `INNER JOIN` (let's put the refactored inner query back):

```
SELECT udc.UserDCID AS UserDCCompForDelCount1
FROM CDICentral.dbo.UserDCComponent AS udc
  INNER JOIN CDICentral.dbo.UserDC AS ud
      ON udc.UserDCID = ud.UserDCID
  LEFT JOIN CVPLocal.dbo.CSWSecurity AS cs
      ON ud.UserID = cs.UserID
WHERE cs.UserID IS NULL
```

Let's read what the new query does: it selects `UserDCComponent`s (`udc`) associated with `UserDC`s (`ud`) that don't have `CSWSecurity` (`cs`) records.

Comment: Also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/4265352). It explains how to achieve different set operations (union, intersect, difference) using SQL joins.